# What SQL Server agent job is running a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent

I have a stored procedure that I know is being run somewhere in SQL Agent I just don't know where. Is there an easy way to find out? Easier than to script all of the jobs and search for it there ?

TIA - Jeff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` table. The `command` field contains the SQL statement for the step.

Here is a sample query to do it:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT
    J.job_id,
    J.name,
    JS.step_id,
    JS.command,
    J.enabled 
FROM
    dbo.sysjobs J
    INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps JS
        ON JS.job_id = J.job_id 
WHERE
    JS.command LIKE N'%string to find%'
```

Please note, that the commands are different for every subsystem in the SQL Agent. You can find SP names in `T-SQL steps`, but you can not find them in `SSIS package` or `PowerShell` or other types of steps.

Here is the documentation for the sysjobsteps table: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187387(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187387%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)